# Revoke Rails Doorkeeper Token via POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, doorkeeper

We know if we utilise the Resource Owner Password Credential flow for doorkeeper, the generated JSON params for POST are based on the URL [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow):

```
{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "user@example.com",
  "password"      : "sekret",
  "client_id"     : "the_client_id",
  "client_secret" : "the_client_secret"
}
```

I would like to perform a token revocation via POST to /oauth/revoke; thus, what parameters which I need in order to perform the POST via JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it figured out; basically I need to send the following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
     -F token=<token>\
     -X POST http://livedo-gunter.codio.io:3000/oauth/revoke
```

This is based on the link [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples#post---oauthrevoke). Basic authorization has to be enabled first though.